# Is there a configuration option in Reinforced.Typings to TsIgnore all properties and methods unless they have a TsProperty attribute set using?

Tags: reinforced-typings

I am using Reinforced.Typings to generate typescript from c#.

There is a way to prevent exporting a property/method by applying the [TsIgnore] attribute to the property/method but I would prefer for it to ignore all properties/methods that don't have [TsFile] or [TsProperty] applied to it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need auto-export switches

```cs
[TsClass(
    AutoExportMethods = false, 
    AutoExportProperties = false,
    AutoExportFields = false)]
public class AutoA
{

}

[TsInterface(AutoExportProperties = false, AutoExportMethods = false)]
public class AutoB
{

}
```

Note that if you are using fluent configuration then - only members will be exported that are specified explicitly e.g. by `.WithPublicMethods()` or `.WithPublicProperties()` invocations etc.