# With reinforced typings, can you set properties on TsInterface by default?

Tags: reinforced-typings

We use the property, `AutoExportMethods` on the `TsInterface`. But we have to remember to add this to every `TsInterface`. I was wondering if we have a way of setting this to true by default in the config for Reinforced Typings?

This is similar to [Is there a configuration option in Reinforced.Typings to TsIgnore all properties and methods unless they have a TsProperty attribute set using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48160967/is-there-a-configuration-option-in-reinforced-typings-to-tsignore-all-properties), but instead of ignoring it per file, we'd like to ignore by default for all files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit `[TsInterface]` attribute and make `AutoExportMethods` `true` by default. And then use your own attribute instead of built-in `[TsInterface]`